# RecyclerView not changing position to bottom element when new item added

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am creating the chat application and using the RecyclerView.

It is stack from bottom.

When new messages are coming. then we need to manually scroll to that position.

It not automatically changing the position like WhatsApp does when new messages received.

Earlier i am using ListView in which its working properly.

Comment: You can manually roll back to the last item by calling recyclerView.scrollToPosition(recyclerView.getAdapter().getItemCount()-1)

Answer (score 5):

You can use `RecyclerView.scrollToPosition()` function. Something like `mRecyclerView.scrollToLastPosition(mAdapter.getCount()-1)`

Answer (score 4):

Try this,

```
recyclerView.scrollToPosition(messages.size()-1);
```

or

```
recyclerView.setStackFromEnd(true)
```